# Programatically adding column and table To CoreData

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, import

I have a sqlite database with more than 100 tables. Each table consists of more than 50 columns. I want to import the database into CoreData.

Can I create the tables and add columns corresponding to sqlite database in CoreData or will I have to manually create the tables one-by-one in CoreData?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a Core Data model programatically. Create an `NSManagedObjectModel`, create some `NSEntityDescription` instances for the model, etc. Everything about a Core Data model is configurable in code, and it's all very well documented.

**But**, you can only do this if you have not yet loaded persistent store that uses the model. Once you the persistent store, the `NSManagedObjectModel` instance must be treated as read-only. Modifying it after loading the store will throw an exception. If you're doing this once to create your initial model, that's fine, but if you want to do it all the time then you're likely to run into problems.

Since you already have this SQLite database, you might be better off keeping it in SQLite and not using Core Data at all. There are a couple of good Objective-C wrappers for SQLite-- check out [PLDatabase](http://code.google.com/p/pldatabase/) and [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 0):

You should use sqlite for this purpose as this still not possible with core data. Core data uses NSManagedObjectModel to create entity models that are built during compile time.

Conclusion - Use Sqlite database for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is currently not possible with CoreData.

To use core data you have to define a persistent store and managed object models. These are classes to represent the entities created in ".xcdatamodeld". These cannot be generated at the runtime.

So better would be to use Sqlite or other database library to create tables dynamically at the run time.